# Facebook graph API explorer query not extracting all columns

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

I am a newbie to this Graph API Explorer, which, I found today, is something that lets me extract data from FB. This is really cool!

I was trying to extract user demographic information using the Graph API explorer from a group with about 2300 members that I own, however for some reason the query is not extracting anything other than name and id as you can see from the screen.

[image]

Experts, why is this happening? I believe I have ticked all relevant permission tick boxes to be able to perform this query.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have provided access to your profile data. You can't get an access token allow you to access any group members details max you can get group members id that it is ;)

Comment: Is there any way to get the members details at all, or is this impossible?

Comment: Still not possible through graph-api...